# Accessing method from another cpp file

Tags: c++

I have two cpp files and two header file, they are a.cpp, b.cpp, a.h and b.h respectively. I have a method defined in the a.cpp file and I would like to call the method in the b.cpp file. How do i go about doing it? Please advice Thank you.

Can i make use of the friend function to do so?

Comment: That method should probably be *declared* in `a.h`, which should be `#include`-ed from `b.cpp`

Comment: Also, do not forget to compile both cpp files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have function prototypes in your header-files and the definitions in your cpp-files. And that you have included a.h in a.cpp and b.h in b.cpp.

Simply add `#include "b.h"` in a.h to reach the functions in b.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
    #include "a.h"
```

in "b.h" .
And Compile ur code with

```
    g++ a.cpp b.cpp
```

Also,

```
    #include "a.h" in a.cpp
    #include "b.h" in b.cpp
```